# Computed column 'AGE' in table 'TABLE1' cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic

Tags: sql, sql-server, alter-table

How to fix this error?

I'm trying to add a column with a check constraint and I'm getting this error even though I persisted the column.

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE1
ADD AGE AS DATEDIFF(YEAR,DateOFBirth,GETDATE()) PERSISTED
CONSTRAINT CHCK_TABLE1_AGE
CHECK (AGE>0 AND AGE<105)
```

Error:

> Computed column 'AGE' in table 'TABLE1' cannot be persisted because
>   the column is non-deterministic.

Comment: You cannot have a constraint since the GetDate() is non-deterministic.
Which means you get a different value each time you execute it.
[Deterministic and Nondeterministic Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/deterministic-and-nondeterministic-functions?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: As the error message is telling you, you *can't* persist it because it's non-deterministic. Adding `PERSISTED` will not somehow fix the value and make it deterministic. (And if it did, the `Age` would be wrong since it would be persisted once and never updated.) Drop the `PERSISTED` and it should be a legal computed column. The `CHECK` is still impossible because SQL Server cannot suddenly declare a row illegal based on a moving clock! (Aside from that -- currently, the oldest human alive is 117 years old; the check seems needlessly restrictive.)

Comment: On a different note, `DATEDIFF(YEAR,DateOFBirth,GETDATE()` doesn't return the age of the person. For example. `DATEDIFF(YEAR, '20000901', GETDATE())` returns 18, however, someone born on that date would not be 18 yet.

Comment: If your goal is to never allow adding people who are currently older than 105, to catch obvious bogus dates, use an `INSERT` trigger. If your goal is to ensure the table *never* contains people older than 105, you'll need a scheduled job or other periodic mechanism to detect people who are "too old" -- although I can't imagine that's a real business goal.

Comment: Age < 105? Really? Humans can live longer than that, though it is uncommon.

Comment: I think a better option is this https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-computed-columns/

Answer (score 0):

Yep, the column is not deterministic, so it cannot be indexed.

The `AGE` column value will change every day (even hour or second), so no index can be created on it.

Off the top of my head the solution I see is to have this column not automatically computed using `AS` but to recompute it every day (night) by a trigger or external process.

This way every day you'll have the **correct age value**, and you'll also have a **fast index to search with**.

Comment: Thank you for ur help :)